# How load whole content file in function?

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I write function which will add new version of file to the table. The user of function should be *call update_file(path_to_file)*. I need load all content from file and store it to the table like:

```
insert into file(new_version, new_content);
```

Now I could find a way to read all content and put it to the table. The [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html#AEN71940) command allows me get the file concatenate as sequence of lines.
I see only way to contact the lines, but I don't like this approach.

Is there some good solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I found the following solution, hope it will be helpful for someone.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION read_file_utf8(path CHARACTER VARYING)
  RETURNS TEXT AS $$
DECLARE
  var_file_oid OID;
  var_record   RECORD;
  var_result   BYTEA := '';
BEGIN
  SELECT lo_import(path)
  INTO var_file_oid;
  FOR var_record IN (SELECT data
                     FROM pg_largeobject
                     WHERE loid = var_file_oid
                     ORDER BY pageno) LOOP
    var_result = var_result || var_record.data;
  END LOOP;
  PERFORM lo_unlink(var_file_oid);
  RETURN convert_from(var_result, 'utf8');
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Maybe somebody knows how to the same when file is located locally? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As another solution may be using of $tag$...$tag$ syntax. It is PostgreSQL's feature, that called 'dollar quoting', it allows you insert any text between tags without quoting. For more details, please visit https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html, 4.1.2.4. Dollar-quoted String Constants